# Variable Scope in PHP MVC Frameworks like CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, scope

I am building a PHP MVC framework like Ruby on Rails but with PHP for learning. The link just in case you want to see it is https://github.com/carlinoo/vinum

I was trying to see the source code of CakePHP as it is very similar to mine. When in aa action in a controller, after the logic of that action/method, it calls the view, a different file that has access to those variables. I cant seem to understand how that works.

How does it call the view after the logic is finished? In CakePHP there’s something called autoRender that if set to true, it renders the appropriate view. How can you do that without calling a function to render the view?

Also, I have a variable scope problem. Let me explain:

```
function func1() {
   $var = 1;
   render();
}

function render() {
   require_once(‘file.php’);
}

// This is file.php
<?php
    echo $var;
 ?>
```

$var one does not exist because of the scope, and i don’t want to declare the variables as global. How do big PHP Frameworks do this? And how does the autoRender actually work? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the "easy" way

```
function func1() {
     $var = 1;
     render(‘file.php’, get_defined_vars());
}

function render($file, $vars = []) {
    extract($vars);
    require $file;  //pass the filename in for reuse
}
```

But it's really messy, and prone to variable name collisions.

> This function returns a multidimensional array containing a list of all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined variables, within the scope that get_defined_vars() is called.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

> Import variables from an array into the current symbol table.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

I would manually build an array of variables, pass that to `render($vars)` and then use `extract()`.

```
function func1() {
     $vars = ['var1' => 1];
     render(‘file.php’, $vars);
}
```

Also I would use `require` instead of `require_once` otherwise if you need to render the same template multiple times it wont work, think like in the case of a post or something you can loop on and call render multiple times.  For example
you may have a "controller"  named `posts.php`

```
render('header.php');
render('menu.php');
foreach($posts as $post){
   render('post.php', $post);
}
render('footer.php');
```

The main Idea behind a template is to eliminate structural PHP mixed into the HTML.  So you would want, smaller chunks of HTML that you can reuse multiple times.  And mostly keep it to echoing variables in the `tempate/view`

Lastly, I would take what I put above as "theoretical"  code, I can't really  test this very well, but that's the basic concept.

**UPDATE**

Here is a quick Psudo-ish Code example of what CakePHP does ( obviously its way more complex then i can do in an answer on here ).
Its mainly the difference between using procedural and object oriented coding.

```
   class Controller{

      protected $data;

      public function index(){
          $this->color = 'pink';
          $this->render('view.php');
      }

     ///magic method
     public function __set( $key, $value){
           $this->data[$key] = $value;
     }

    /*
       you can do the same thing with a normal method

       public function set( $key, $value){
           $this->data[$key] = $value;
       }

       but instead of doign $this->color = 'pink';
       you would do $this->set('color', 'pink');

     */

     public function render($file){
         /*
            obviously I can easily access $this->data['color']
            from within the scope of the same class. 
         */
         extract($this->data);         
         include $file;

       /*
         or any number of other things
         like 

             $contents = file_get_contents($file);

             foreach( $this->data as $key => $value )
                $contents = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', value , $contents);

             echo $contents;

        for tags like  {color} etc.
       */
     }
 }
```

Right here is every method they are using.

https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html

And here is the source code for their controller,

https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#583-622

Honestly I wouldn't recommend using the magic metods like `__set` `__get` etc. because it Makes the code

- harder to read
- harder to maintain
- more prone to error
- less efficient, performance wise.

For example

```
$this->set('data', 'foo');
```

Is safe, but using

```
$this->data = 'foo';
```

Will wipe out that data array property, because in my example the data gets put into a class property named `data` as an array, so calling `$this->data = foo;` accesses the already existing property and overwrites it. Which then means you have to do all kinds of checks and other things to make sure nothing gets overwritten, and anytime you add any properties you have to deal with that kind of stuff.  And if you miss something you may not find it for months and then one day, you set `data` in a controller and it all falls apart.

For reference.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Anyway

Comment: Thanks for your time. I get what you are saying. But I kinda wanted to know how do Frameworks like Laravel or CakePHP can call a function like render and it will render the view using the local variables of the action.

Comment: They don't.  they use `Controller::set()` https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html  And store it in the controller class, which they already know because of how MVC frameworks do routing, then they just access it from the Controller.  You don't see it but Its not magic.  And its not something you can do with 2 function calls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You opened my mind to be able to find ways to do it :)

Comment: Sure I done a lot of this stuff, but Like I said it's best to keep it simple.  I used to code stuff dynamically and with the magic methods because I thought it was `cool` then I had to debug and maintain it ... lol

Comment: oh I understand. I am trying to build a simple Framework kinda like Ruby on Rails. Any advice you could give me? How would you personally approach my problem? Thanks a million haha.

Comment: @CarlinoGonzalez - Sorry, but I am way on another level of doing it that way.  I am currently building my own framework, My GitHub https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix A lot of this stuff is in the works (so it largely doesn't work at this point), but I am building a Token / Lexer for Html.  Think like Twig Template engine but more advanced.  Right now I am working on breaking some parts out into their own Composer Packages `actually` lol

Comment: My template engine will use a Dependency Injection Container to supply the templates with their `variable` data.  The Lexer part of it will take the Template ( text file ) and build an actual PHP class from it ( it's not easy to do )  If you want a somewhat simpler example of how that works I wrote this for another question https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/JasonDecoder.php It parses Json Object data, ( instead of Json Strings like `json_decode()` )  You can even test that one online here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2917e4bb8ef847df97edbf0bb8f415a10d13c9f

Comment: sounds REALLY interesting. I am gonna follow you on github!!. I am just a Computer Science student trying to spend my time doing something cool and learning. My knowledge is quite limited at this stage of my life haha!

Comment: I'm a CIO with 7 years PHP experience, but I was where you are at.  Which is why I help people on Stack Overflow.  Cheers, and have a good night!